# Not able to click on a Iframe button– Java- Appium

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, selendroid

I was trying to click on a button which is present inside an Iframe. Test is showing successful but not clicking on that button. I am writing scripts using Java. Please find the below code.

First I switched to webview from native app using

```
driver.context("WEBVIEW_0");
```

After that Switch to Iframe using

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe_a");
Thread.sleep(10000);
WebElement PlayIcon = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='plt-playBtnForIpad']"));
PlayIcon.click();
```

But PlayIcon is not clicking. Its not showing any error.
Can anyone please help me regarding this.

Thanks,
Tariful Islam